# What is the real world application of Java Native Interface?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have successfully executed a simple program using JNI and I know what JNI is But I wonder where it is used in real time and why we need JNI while we can do anything in java.

Comment: We cannot "_do anything in java_". In fact, Java runs of the JVM and the JVM is partly Java and partly native code. Look at any low level Java classes and you'll find the magic word `native`. Any interaction between the JVM and the hardware must go through `native`.

Comment: See also things such as [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) or [Apache Ignite](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/off-heap-memory).

Comment: I've used JNI to access or perform network based operations, specific to Windows, such as mapping/listing network access points. I used it to listen to file system events (before nio2), monitor USB/CD activity, list and manipulate running processes, list system information (dns name, etc), I've used to to convert "long file names" to "short file names" and back again - There are a lot of functionality which is agnostic to a single OS which is either not implement on other systems or is to difficult to abstract in a meaningful way

Comment: Yes.I clearly see that now

Comment: Even java.awt package uses native libraries refer link :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/awt/AWT_Native_Interface.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ... while we can do anything in java

That's the flaw in your thinking.  There some things that you cannot do in Java.  There are other things that you cannot do *efficiently* in Java.

Examples include:

- interacting with OS functions in ways that the Java APIs don't support,
- calling libraries implemented in other programming languages, and
- interacting with memory-mapped devices.

Comment: Does swing in java has anything to do with JNI??

Comment: Maybe it uses JNI under the hood.  You can download the source and look for yourself ... if your are curious.

Comment: After looking the source code ,I found that java applet's mouse events uses native libraires

Comment: (IMO that is a good outcome.  1) You now have a copy of the code to look at.  2) You are starting to find your way around the code.  3) You have satisfied your curiosity!)

Answer (score 4):

An important application of JNI is to wrap existing libraries; the alternative would be to port huge projects (with the cost associated with writing the new code and testing).

See in example QuantLib, https://www.quantlib.org . They port the whole library to Java with SWIG, which in turn uses JNI.

Answer (score 3):

I will add one real life use case here. Our software application connects to different vendors to get data from them. For this we use vendor supplied api's. 2 of our vendors only have C/C++ API's and since our application is in Java we use JNI to communicate with these API's.

Although JNI is quite brittle to use but if it did not exist it would mean we would have to rewrite parts of our application in C++ which would be tens of thousands of lines of code + the maintenance cost of maintaining code bases in 2 different languages.

One possible way to avoid JNI in our situation is to have messaging middleware that could be used for communications between Java and C++ process's but then we have latency issues + configuration and maintenance of another complex piece of software to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Although I haven't used JNI lately but about 6 or 7 years ago, I was working on a Java application where we were implementing cryptography. I implemented some of the cryptographic algorithms in C to improve their performance and used JNI as a wrapper.